# math experts - express log/ln function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, math, maps

I would like to find log/ln equation and express in javascript to graph google maps zoom against km distance. Unfortunately my javascript skills are better than my math skills.

Values are approximate.

```
km  zoom    
5   13  
10  11  
20  10  
40  9   
80  8   
160 7   
180 6
```

something like:

```
zoom = Math.round((13/Math.log(km)));
```

Comment: What are you asking? for a math formula that approximates the zoom value you listed, given the km you listed?

Comment: indeed. maybe I should be posting on mathoverflow.com :)

Comment: `var E = m * Math.pow(c, 2);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use the equation

> zoom = 11 - log(km/10)/log(2),

which matches the zoom for your km values between 10 and 160.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably closer to what you want:

```
zoom = Math.round((18/Math.log(km))+2);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell from the approximate values, but it ought to be in terms of logarithms, as you guessed.

You could try [curve fitting](http://www.google.com/search?q=curve+fitting+log), since the approximate values don't seem to match a consistent log base (they're near log base 2 at the bottom, base sqrt(2) at the top).